# Where does Excel VBA execution control go after a VBA event handler routine ends

Tags: excel, vba, events

I have a main vba macro that is in an infinite loop waiting for the worksheet.selectionchange Events. That event handler assigns some global variables with the row & column of the selection. When it completes that assignment does control return back to the main vba macro where it was paused by the event? The main vba macro will do different things based upon the row & column values.

Comment: Typically you do not write a loop to "wait" for events in Excel, so it would be useful to post some code along with your description.  It sounds like you may be doing something unusual, but we can't really know what that looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Comment:
I am doing the wrong thing with the wrong program. I am using Google Excel to store a spreadsheet that is the layout of a backgammon board. I want to play against someone else and the sharing of Google docs seemed like a convenient way. I did not want to have to spend time learning how to use sharing for myself, so I took the lazy-man's approach. I am using the activate-worksheet event to kick off my near-endless loop . That loop is looking for non-zero values of the global row and column that was selected. The selection-change event writes the value from the event data into those variables. When the loop sees non-zero values it clears them and processes the buffered values accordingly. I can post code if you really want to see it. BTW I started using Google script macros, but that was a whole new development environment and remarkably slow. (I've been programming (hacking?) for over 40 years so I've learned enough development environments, let alone languages). Before moving to a full VBA approach, I thought that I could use my previous experiences with python and spreadsheets, but the Excel program opens the file in such a way that my python code gets blocked from opening it. I do need the interactive and progromatic interface to the spreadsheet, so I've ended up with VBA, which I have used for many other programs/utiities I have written.

Comment: Control returns to where it was interrupted by the event. Close this question